# Get value of a key in etcd if key contains binary value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, etcd

I have an etcd key, which contains binary value:

```
/person/��h��1Ðn��;�Fx/timestamp
20230301091005
```

I query that key-value by:

```
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=server:2379 --cert ca.pem --key ca.key --cacert cacert.pem get /person/ --prefix
```

I wish to delete that particular key `��h��1Ðn��;�Fx` from the etcd, but cannot refer to this key in [Python etcd API](https://github.com/kragniz/python-etcd3) function:

```
import etcd3

client = etcd3.client(host="server", port="2379", cert_cert="ca.pem", ca_cert="cacert.pem", cert_key="ca.key")
print(client.get_prefix_response(key_prefix="/person/", keys_only=True))
```

Outputs that `/person/��h��1Ðn��;�Fx/timestamp` looks like `/person/\377\273h\260\2731\303\220n\031\271\235;\233Fx/timestamp`
And querying for that value:

```
client.get(key="/person/\377\273h\260\2731\303\220n\031\271\235;\233Fx/timestamp")
```

I get:

```
(None, None)
```

How could I query these binary keys in etcd?

Comment: `print(repr(value))` is much more useful than `print(value)` when what you're trying to get is a string formed in such a way that you can use it in Python code.

Comment: "binary value" is not a meaningful description. It appears from a brief search that etcd keys are fundamentally sequences of bytes, **not necessarily meaningful text**. It is therefore necessary to know what actual bytes are in the key, not simply how the text appears when a particular encoding is assumed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel UTF-8 encoded bytes, however `client.get(key="/person/\377\273h\260\2731\303\220n\031\271\235;\233Fx/timestamp".encode("utf-8"))` doesn't help either, still `(None, None)`

Comment: That is definitely not valid UTF-8 data. To use `.encode` you would have to start with a `bytes` object. `b"/person/\377\273h\260\2731\303\220n\031\271\235;\233Fx/timestamp".decode('utf-8')` gives an exception as I expect, because `\377` means a 0xFF byte, and **a UTF-8-encoded character can't start with that**.

Comment: BTW, piping the output of `etcdctl` into `xxd` would make a more useful description of the key's actual name, being something we could actually compare against your Python string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
dataJson = subprocess.run(("env", "ETCDCTL_API=3", "etcdctl", "--endpoints=server:2379", "--cert", "ca.pem", "--key", "ca.key", "--cacert", "cacert.pem", "get", "/person/", "--prefix", "-w", "json"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, check=True)

pyDict = json.loads(dataJson.stdout)
```

Note, that `pyDict` is already a Python data type, so you can perform all search operations on that dict freely.

Inside `pyDict` all etcd `keys` are stored as base64.
So when you wish to query that so called binary `key`'s value, just decode it as:

```
print(client.get(base64.b64decode(yourkey)))
```

Don't forget to `import base64, json, subprocess` :)